# React table with data in props

Tags: reactjs, html-table

I have 2 components - *Table* and *TableRow*. TableRow get a data from props.

TableRow:

```
render(){
    return(
        <tr>
            {Object.values(this.props.data).forEach(value =>{
                return(<td>value</td>)
            })}
        </tr>
    )
}
```

But in result I have empty row. What I do wrong?

Comment: Can you please share more screen shot, what value your provide as a props

Comment: Assuming props.data is an object you need to wrap the value variable like this : `return <td>{value}</td>`

Comment: i provide next object:

{
  "data": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Roman"
  }
}

TableRow get this props, I see this in DevTools in Chrome

Comment: @RyanZeelie, it's not help

Comment: shouldn't it be `{value.name}` instead?

Comment: @buzz, it's no help too

Comment: can you post the response you're getting as props with your question...and provide as much details you can please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I resolve problem, by use `map`

```
{Object.keys(data).map(key =>{
    let cell = data[key]
    if (key != 'changeMode'){
        return(<td>{cell}</td>)
    }
})}
```